Directus extension issue
I have run Directus 11.1.1 in my local machine with docker. I have also add weather API as an extension. Now, I want to add another POST API as another extension, but not able to do that. Would you please help me in this regard?
I tried to add another extension like weather API

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
